# Find LocalAppData for a different Windows user

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a Windows Service that is responsible for deploying desktop applications.  It detects windows logons, and then should install applications into local appdata, and start menu icons in the correct place.

What is the correct way to find a given user's local app data folder?  I have a session id, but no win32 user token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved it.

I was able to retrieve the user token given the session id by calling WTSQueryUserToken.

I was then able to present this token to SHGetKnownFolderPath, which returned the correct path for local app data.

Comment: Prior to Vista, you can pass the user token to `SHGetFolderPath()` instead.

Comment: I always get 'false' from WTSQueryUserToken, I guess its something with permissions etc like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717691/wtsqueryusertoken-returning-false, did you encounter the same issue? how did you solve it?

Comment: @Alonzzo2 no i didn't have that issue.  Did you check the permission requirements? You need to be running as LocalSystem and have the SE_TCB_NAME permission