# WTSQueryUserToken returning FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm making a interactive service on Windows 7, on visual studio 2015, that is able to initialize an application UI but the WTSQueryUserToken method is retuning false.

```
IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;             

if (WTSQueryUserToken(tSessionInfo.SessionID, out hToken)) //FALSE returned
```

I really don't have much experience with C# so I've searched online to get an answer and I found that "To call this function (WTSQueryUserToken) successfully, the calling application must be running within the context of the LocalSystem account and have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege", but I don't know how can I give the application SE_TCB_NAME privilege privilege on the code. Does anyone know how can I code this?

Thank you.

Comment: let me understand u have a windows service which will be running in local system account and that service will launch the UI Application in user session ..??  this what you want to achieve crct me if iam wrng.??

Comment: @RaviKanth Yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to do impersonation to launch the application under the user account.

Here is a sample of that, showing also how to get the SE_TCB_NAME privilege.

In this sample we first get the security token for the Current Process and then escalate the privileges to include the SE_TCB_NAME privilege.

Once we are done with that then we take the SessionId of the explorer process, and duplicate the security token associated with it, which we then pass to CreateProcessAsUser.

```
public class Impersonation
    {
        #region DLL Imports
        internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
        internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
        internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
        internal const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
        internal const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        internal const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0X00000004;
        internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
        internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
        internal const int MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;
        internal const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
        internal const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
        internal const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

        internal const string SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeShutdownPrivilege";
        internal const string SE_TCB_NAME = "SeTcbPrivilege";
        internal const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";

        private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;
        public static IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        public static IntPtr dupeTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        const string SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME = "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege";

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        internal struct TokPriv1Luid
        {
            public int Count;
            public long Luid;
            public int Attr;
        }

        struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }

        struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public uint cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public uint dwX;
            public uint dwY;
            public uint dwXSize;
            public uint dwYSize;
            public uint dwXCountChars;
            public uint dwYCountChars;
            public uint dwFillAttribute;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }
        public enum ShowCommands : int
        {
            SW_HIDE = 0,
            SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1,
            SW_NORMAL = 1,
            SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
            SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
            SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,
            SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
            SW_SHOW = 5,
            SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
            SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
            SW_SHOWNA = 8,
            SW_RESTORE = 9,
            SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10,
            SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11,
            SW_MAX = 11
        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(
            IntPtr hwnd,
            string lpOperation,
            string lpFile,
            string lpParameters,
            string lpDirectory,
            ShowCommands nShowCmd);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr hToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, Int32 dwDesiredAccess,
                            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
                            Int32 ImpersonationLevel, Int32 dwTokenType,
                            ref IntPtr phNewToken);

        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(out IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
            IntPtr hToken,
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
        #endregion

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Impersonation));

        private static void WriteToLog(string message)
        {
            log.Debug(message);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Duplicates the token information derived 
        /// from the logged in user's credentials. This 
        /// is required to run the application on the 
        /// logged in users desktop.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the application was successfully started in the user's desktop.</returns>
        public static bool ExecuteAppAsLoggedOnUser(string AppName, string CmdLineArgs)
        {
            WriteToLog("In ExecuteAppAsLoggedOnUser for all users.");
            IntPtr LoggedInUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr DuplicateToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ShellProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (!OpenProcessToken(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, ref LoggedInUserToken))
            {
                WriteToLog("OpenProcessToken failed: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Below part for increasing the UAC previleges to the token.
                TokPriv1Luid tp = new TokPriv1Luid();
                tp.Count = 1;
                tp.Luid = 0;
                if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, ref tp.Luid))
                {
                    WriteToLog("LookupPrivilegeValue failed: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return false;
                }

                tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
                if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(LoggedInUserToken, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    WriteToLog("OpenProcessToken failed: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return false;
                }
                CloseHandle(LoggedInUserToken);
            }

            List<Process> explorerProcessList = new List<Process>();
            string trayProcessName = AppName.Substring(AppName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1, AppName.Length - AppName.LastIndexOf(@"\") - 5);
            foreach (Process explorerProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
            {
                bool IsProcessRunningForUser = false;
                foreach (Process PHTrayProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName(trayProcessName))
                {
                    if (explorerProcess.SessionId == PHTrayProcess.SessionId)
                    {
                        if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug(trayProcessName + " is already running for user SessionId " + explorerProcess.SessionId);
                        IsProcessRunningForUser = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5 && explorerProcess.SessionId > 0)
                    || Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5)
                    && !IsProcessRunningForUser)
                {
                    if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug(trayProcessName + " is not running for user SessionId " + explorerProcess.SessionId);
                    explorerProcessList.Add(explorerProcess);
                }
            }

            if (null != explorerProcessList && explorerProcessList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Process explorerProcess in explorerProcessList)
                {
                    Process ShellProcess = explorerProcess;
                    ShellProcess.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

                    try
                    {
                        int tokenRights = MAXIMUM_ALLOWED; //TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;
                        if (!OpenProcessToken(ShellProcess.Handle, tokenRights, ref ShellProcessToken))
                        {
                            WriteToLog("Unable to OpenProcessToken " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                            return false;
                        }

                        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                        sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

                        if (!DuplicateTokenEx(ShellProcessToken, tokenRights, ref sa, 2, 1, ref DuplicateToken))
                        {
                            WriteToLog("Unable to duplicate token " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                            return false;
                        }

                        WriteToLog("Duplicated the token " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
                        si.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);

                        IntPtr UserEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
                        uint dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
                        if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(out UserEnvironment, ShellProcessToken, true))
                        {
                            WriteToLog("Unable to create user's enviroment block " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
                        }
                        //string userName = getUserName(UserEnvironment);

                        //WriteToLog("UserName:::" + userName);

                        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(DuplicateToken, AppName, (CmdLineArgs == null) ? string.Empty : CmdLineArgs, ref processAttributes, ref threadAttributes, true, dwCreationFlags, UserEnvironment, AppName.Substring(0, AppName.LastIndexOf('\\')), ref si, out pi))
                        {
                            WriteToLog("Unable to create process " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 740)
                            {
                                WriteToLog("Please check the installation as some elevated permissions is required to execute the binaries");
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                        Process trayApp = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(pi.dwProcessId));
                        trayApp.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (ShellProcessToken != null) CloseHandle(ShellProcessToken);
                        if (DuplicateToken != null) CloseHandle(DuplicateToken);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WriteToLog("No user has been identified to have logged into the system.");
                return false;
            }
            WriteToLog("Finished ExecuteAppAsLoggedOnUser for all users.");
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Impersonate the user credentials. This would be required by 
        /// the service applications to impersonate the logged in user
        /// credentials to launch certain applications or applying the
        /// power scheme.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the impersonation is successful.</returns>
        public static bool ImpersonateUser()
        {
            // For simplicity I'm using the PID of System here
            //if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug("GetaProcess for Explorer"); 
            Process Pname = GetaProcess("explorer");
            //This can be null if no user has not logged into the system.
            if (Pname == null) return false;

            int pid = Pname.Id;
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            if (OpenProcessToken(proc.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref hToken)) // != 0)
            {
                WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(hToken);
                //log.Debug(newId.Owner);
                try
                {
                    const int SecurityImpersonation = 2;
                    dupeTokenHandle = DupeToken(hToken,
                    SecurityImpersonation);
                    if (IntPtr.Zero == dupeTokenHandle)
                    {
                        string s = String.Format("Dup failed {0}, privilege not held",
                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        throw new Exception(s);
                    }

                    impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
                    return true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseHandle(hToken);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string s = String.Format("OpenProcess Failed {0}, privilege not held", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                throw new Exception(s);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Duplicate the token for user impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Token to duplicate for impersonation</param>
        /// <param name="Level">Impersonation security level, currently hardcored to 2</param>
        /// <returns>Returns duplicated token</returns>
        public static IntPtr DupeToken(IntPtr token, int Level)
        {
            IntPtr dupeTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool retVal = DuplicateToken(token, Level, ref dupeTokenHandle);
            return dupeTokenHandle;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the process running locally on the machine.
        /// If the specified process does not exists, it 
        /// returns back the current process.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="processname">Process name to get</param>
        /// <returns>Returns back the process</returns>
        public static Process GetaProcess(string processname)
        {
            Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname);
            if (aProc.Length > 0) return aProc[0];
            else
            {
                //if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug("Explorer is not running");
                Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                return currentProcess;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Roleback the impersonation if applied previously.
        /// </summary>
        public static void UndoImpersonate()
        {
            impersonatedUser.Undo();
            if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hToken);
            if (dupeTokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(dupeTokenHandle);
            return;
        }
    }
```

And then you can just do

```
Impersonation.ExecuteAppAsLoggedOnUser("applicationName", null);
```

Comment: Now I got an error on CreateProcessAsUser. Error 1314. Got that same error before with another class.

Comment: u can refer to dis sight to resoolve this issue the user must be in adminstative groups run .. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c905c900-cae1-4081-b0c9-00f10238e7ad/createprocessasuser-failed?forum=clr

Comment: you are the worlds life saver!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can either set **Act as part of the operating system** in **Local security policy**, or you can also set the privileges programmatically using LsaAddAccountRights.