# Is there a way to pass credential to WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently i have a winform where i need to open report in WebBrowser Control. I am using impersonation method to view as different user. But somehow the WebBrowser will pop up a windows security authentication for me to enter my credential. When i input the credential as someone that has the right to view the report (not my credential) it will just show a blank page. Not even a message that says:

> The permissions granted to user 'Domain\first.last' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

The First Page:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (new ImpersonateUser("TestUsername", Environment.UserDomainName, "TestPassword"))
        {
            Form2 reportForm = new Form2();
            reportForm.Text = "Test";
            reportForm.GetReportUrl("http://url/");
            reportForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The Second Page:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = Environment.UserName;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        public void GetReportUrl(string repUrl)
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(repUrl);
        }

    }
```

Can someone explains to me why is this happening? And how i can fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

But i didn't get why you have to do impersonation to launch a form, from the above code you are not doing any by doing impersonation.

if you are facing the problem in launching a application under user profile then the below link will be helpful.

[WTSQueryUserToken returning FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717691/wtsqueryusertoken-returning-false)