# Start an application or batch file using Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, backup

I made a C# application that backups some files and sends it to FTP or Dropbox. This application works in servers. But sometimes my application crashes or closes somehow. It must stay open all the time. I thought I can make a Windows Service to check my app status. If my app shuts down opens it again. I created the service. I used the `Process.Start()` method to open my app again. But it didn't work. I changed the code to open an a batch file that opens my app. It didn't work too.  Then I searched this situation. I learned Windows services can't open an app from desktop. I didn't find a solution for this.

Is there any solutions for this or is there any different method from Windows service that I can use for open my app again?

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you make your application as windows service application?

Comment: @Nantharupan Windows services cannot call upon third party executables.

Comment: There is a form for users in my applications. So I can't convert it to a windows service.

Comment: Windows service cannot invoke a Modal Window of any kind including a form, so your better off creating a console app that performs the monitoring. I do not see why this simple console app will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution will be is to create one exe(Monitor.exe) just to monitor if your app process is running. If not launch your application.

The single responsibility of Monitor.exe is to ensure your main app is up and running

Comment: Actually, the reason is I choose a service, service works in backgroud. I am not sure an executable works all the time like a service. This monitor.exe can close in any case like my application.

Comment: Services run on Level 0 and will also have a process associated with it, and they are also prone from erroring out.
Have you checked to find out why your application is crashing ?
The third approach is to try Windows Task Scheduler  ;)

Comment: @YusufİslamTek sure, exe can work all the time. you can have an exe running as taskbar app on Windows and have some background thread performing all the work and reporting back to your little icon-exe

Comment: @YusufİslamTek I guess you are still figuring out the solution, let us know if you want any more help

Comment: @Clint I didn't get a chance to look this solutions. When I try these methods I will share results immediately.

Comment: @Clint I figured out my problem with create a small exe like you said. Frankly, I have no time to test other solutions about service. The exe is running without any problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason your application should crash. For this add handling for unlhandled exception on start

```
// For service
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ...
// For windows forms
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

Then your logic should be- you start your execution thread and if that thread dies it should be handled here

```
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Log the exception, display it, etc
    // Restart your processor on new thread
    // count number of breakages. If it exceeds certain criteria, like total number,
    // or number per minute, stop service ans send yourself email - 
    // hey your service encounters too many exceptions
}
```

As far as component part of your question - write your logic in DLL and then you can re-use it in the service or application, or elsewhere

But with all that said, your code should handle all the exception and prevent unhandled ones. And also it could be a little different based on framework version. See `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute`

Comment: Thanks for this useful method. I will add this to my project. I found a few solution for Windows service I will try them. If they don't work I can create a small application as you said.

Answer (score 0):

> I learned Windows services can't open an app from desktop.

This is wrong, services can start an app as the desktop user on windows. But you need to do some workarounds to make it work.

The problem is that the windows services are running in a different session than your windows desktop user. And their interactions are not directly allowed. This is called: [Session 0 Isolation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Ask-The-Performance-Team/Application-Compatibility-Session-0-Isolation/ba-p/372361)

What you need to do is, start your desktop application "as the desktop user" from the windows service.
Windows has [CreateProcessAsUserA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) to help with that.

OK so Where is my code?

[Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718244/10413298)
I really like this example class. "Impersonation.cs"
Because, it makes it very easy for you to use the CreateProcessAsUser function. You can call the function like:

> Impersonation.ExecuteAppAsLoggedOnUser("applicationName", null);

Also make sure you give Replace a Process Level Token privilege to the user:
https://defaultreasoning.com/2017/01/16/migration-assistant-error-replace-process-level-token/

Comment: I will try this and give results. Thanks.